# Spring Boot+Spring JPA+Spring Batch is not able to persist data in consistent way

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm using Sprig-Boot + Spring-JPA + Spring-Batch for database CRUD operations in a batch application. Couple of times I find that application is running fine without any exception but data is not getting inserted in DB. To resolve this behaviour tried below workarounds which are totally irrelevant to problem but surprisingly they work intermittently.

- Added logger just after the save() call in service layer.
- Added flush() just after the save() call in service layer.
- Changed propagation level between REQUIRED and REQUIRED_NEW back and forth in service layer.

Above workarounds worked for couple of days but again I face this intermittent issue. I also tried EntityManager(instead of Spring-JPA) but it also behaves in same way.

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class ServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryImpl repositoryImpl;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    /* @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) */
    public void save(List<MyCustomObject> objects) {
        repositoryImpl.save(objects);
        /* log.info("Added records in DB"); */ 
        /* repositoryImpl.flush(); */
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    /* @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) */
    public void save(MyCustomObject object) {
        repositoryImpl.save(object);
        /* log.info("Added records in DB"); */
        /* repositoryImpl.flush(); */   
    }
}
```

**RepositoryImpl.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public interface RepositoryImpl extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyCustomObject, String> { 

    List<MyCustomObject> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    List<MyCustomObject> findByCity(String city);
}
```

**MyCustomObject.java**

```
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity(name = "myCustomObject")
    @Table(name = "MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT")
    public class MyCustomObject implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5187508219838537687L;

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT_SEQ_ID", sequenceName = "MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT_SEQ_ID", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT_SEQ_ID")
        @Column(name="MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT_ID")
        private Long myCustomObjectId;

        @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name="CITY")
        private String city;
}
```

**MyCustomJobConfiguration.java**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class MyCustomJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job myCustomJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step webIdStoreStep, MyCustomJobBatchListener myCustomJobBatchListener) {

        return jobs.get("myCustomJob").listener(myCustomJobBatchListener)
                                      .start(myCustomPersistStep)
                                      .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step myCustomPersistStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, MyCustomPersistTasklet myCustomPersistTasklet) {

           TaskletStep step = stepBuilderFactory.get("myCustomPersistStep")
                                                .tasklet(myCustomPersistTasklet)
                                                .build();
           step.setAllowStartIfComplete(Boolean.TRUE);
           return step;
       }
}
```

**MyCustomPersistTasklet.java**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomPersistTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        List<MyCustomObject> objects = getMyCustomObjects();
        serviceImpl.save(objects);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

**MyCustomDto.java**

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class MyCustomDto {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String city;
}
```

**MyCustomProcessDto.java**

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class MyCustomProcessDto {

    private MyCustomDto myCustomDto;

    private OtherCustomInfoDto otherCustomInfoDto;
}
```

**CustomSpringBatchJobConfigurer.java**

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({ ServiceConfiguration.class })
public class CustomSpringBatchJobConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer configurer(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository getJobRepository(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager)
            throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        factory.setValidateTransactionState(false);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SyncTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistry jobRegistry() {
        return new MapJobRegistry();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor bean = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        bean.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I tried formatting code in best possible way. Happy to share if more information is needed. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And you expect an answer without seeing your batch job? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with that. (For instance by adding your batch job configuration).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for correcting.  Added all batch configuration

Comment: @M.Deinum Any help ?

Comment: Why are you even using Spring Batch? You aren't using any of its features. Instead create a reader which reads your items and add `JpaItemWriter` for writing. That way you have the features Spring Batch uses. Your DTOs aren't used anywhere so not sure why you post them, also not sure what your `getObjects` is doing.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using reader, processor and writer in next step. They are in next step after **myCustomPersistStep**. Tasklet **myCustomPersistStep** has got responsibility to call a REST endpoint and persists same data into **MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT** table by calling **ServiceImpl** . Since **myCustomPersistStep** persists data intermittently so there is no point to execute next step which includes reader, processor and writer acting on **MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT** table.

Comment: You can perfectly do that with a reader and writer (no need for a task let) added advantage is that you get more information on your work.

Comment: @M.Deinum So **getObjects()** method is calling a REST endpoint and parsing response data into **MyCustomObject**.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, My batch application includes couple of more jobs which are completely written in reader,processor and writer manner without any Tasklet. But when my application stops persisting data into DB, every job suffer from same issue.

Comment: Where is class with @EnableBatchProcessing?

Comment: @milbr Just added.

Comment: @milbr Any help ?

Comment: Why do you have:  factory.setValidateTransactionState(false); ?

Comment: @milbr Set it **false** because I don't want newly created JobExecution to look for any existing transaction. This way I'm trying to make new born JobExecution to start with its own transaction without depending on any existing one.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?